# WSO EMM Application Not Installing and makes my /emm endpoint inactive

Tags: wso2, mdm

I have been using WSO2 EMM for like 3months now and it's working fine as for production purposes, but today we started rolling out applications and policy making. So, I started reading the Documentation for production purposes. I uploaded my Apps, but when I get to /emm endpoint and try to use the Application Management and clicked the App, it just hangs everything no endPoint ("/emm", "/publisher", "/carbon")works after clicking an App in the **App Management** unless I restart my server before any endPoint ("/emm", "/publisher", "/carbon") starts working again starts working again. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the terminal when you click on app? Is it an enterprise app (iOS / Android) or market place app (iOS / Android) Also what is your server setup, i.e., OS, java version, etc.? Can you check if you are able to install an app from the Store to an enrolled device? I need more information in order to figure out the issue.

Comment: I don't know if I've an error, cause it's running as a service and I don't know where to check my Log there. It's android and it's not market place app. Yes, my server is setup with (Ubuntu Server, Java 6). I did something yesterday. I went to  `Configuration -> Policy -> Edit Policy and scroll down to mobile Application and attach an app to the policy` I was getting the app as a necessary app to be installed on the devices. But, if I click on app in App Management Tab, it still hangs it

Comment: The logs can be found at "<EMM_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log". Try to remove the policy and then try to install the app from the Store and also try if you are able to install it via the App Management Console. It takes sometime to load the page, therefore check using Firebug if the page has been fully loaded.

Comment: This is my Log here [link](http://pastebin.com/52mkDx6g)

Comment: I've been using Firebug and For like 30mins, it's still showing the loading icon there, does it take it hours?

Comment: It doesn't take that much time. Can you please check if you are able to install the App via the Store? Want to check if this is issue if happening only in the App Management Console or also in the Store.

Comment: It works by installing from Store, I just tried it and just admin @Nira

Comment: As mentioned by @Dilshan (below), there are some database lock errors in your log. Kill all instance and start the server. If the issue persists, I think it must be in the App management console page since you are able to install the app via the Store.

Comment: Yeah, I think that page has a problem. Can I install for other devices from the store? And how, cause admin device is the only I'm seeing here.

Comment: You can only push apps from the store to the currently logged in user's devices. You can create a policy with the apps that you want to install and in "Assign to Resources", assign the policy to the user / role / platform. The policy will be push to the device.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs your database is locked.

org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: 
    Database Error - Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process".
    Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode; SQL statement:

Try to kill all the processes related to wso2server and restart the server.

Comment: Dilshan,if your meaning of Server mode is running as a service on my linux server, yes that's what I'm doing. If I kill all process and go back and click that, it's still same thing

Comment: you also have to remove the lock files which is created in the server in <EMM_HOME>/repository/database directory